# Operator overloading= and templates double value does not work only int

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

Working on a project for vector addition alongside templates and in main when calling on my class VecXd example -> VecXd x,y,z; the values returned are correct, but when calling from main again using VecXd x,y,z; the values my operator= returns go out of scope, does anyone have an idea why?

```
template< class V >
class VecXd {
  std::size_t dimension;
  V* vecArr;
public:
  ...
  VecXd& operator=(const VecXd &rhs)
  { 
     // cout << rhs.vecArr[0] << "-= value at 0 rhs" << endl; value is fine
     dimension = rhs.dimension;   
     cout << dimension << "operator= dimension test!" << endl; ///dimension check
     vecArr = new V[dimension];

     for(int i = 0; i < rhs.dimension; i++)
     {
        vecArr[i] = rhs.vecArr[i];
        cout << vecArr[i] << " our new value (op=)" << endl;                 
     } 

     return *this;    
   }
};
```

Comment: the template class is template <class V>

Comment: You can edit your question. Please do not amend your question in the comments, it makes it harder to read.

Comment: it was not appearing just kept saying template not including the class but its fixed now! :D

Comment: you should add code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Your copy assignment operator has a memory leak here. Why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: I can't really make head or tails of your question. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaking memory by assigning `vecArr` to newly allocated memory before freeing any previously allocated memory.

Other than that, the correctness of your code hinges on the parts not provided here, in particular the correct maintainance of `vecArr` and `dimension`.

**Why not using `std::vector` or `std::array`?** Often, the number of dimensions is known at compile time and fixed. Then using `std::array` is ideal. You can extend it (either by public inheritance or by having it as a data member) by further methods for, say, vector sums and dot product etc.

Comment: you make a great point on memory leaking and freeing up vecArr and dimension I'm going to look into my program, std::vector and array would make life easier, but as part of a project my goal is to to live with out them sadly...

Comment: without `std` library methods, it's not really C++